# Identifying Maven and Java version for a project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image] I have a maven project. Since, I am relatively new to maven and java, I have been trying to identify the correct configuration to build the project in maven. I keep getting this error

> "Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 3.0".

How do we identify the correct version of java and maven with which a project was originally created? Additionally, I wanted to know is every version of eclipse compatible with every version of java and maven? If not, how do I identify the correct combination?

Comment: It doesn't matter what version of maven was used when creating the project. It only matters that you use a version of maven that supports the features declared in the `pom.xml`, in this case you need to run a newer version of maven because the `pom.xml` declares a version of the compiler plugin that requires maven version 3.0. From the screenshot you posted, it looks like you're building with Eclipse and it's using maven 3.0 so I'm not sure why that doesn't work. Can you run maven from the command line?

Comment: For both it's safe to always use the latest (not "experimental") version

Comment: Ok. So, till now Java Compiler was set to 1.6. Then I saw this in the properties section of the POM "<project.java.version>1.5</project.java.version>" and then restarted eclipse. That helped resolve me the version issue with maven. However, I get this issue now "Unable to initialise extensions
Component descriptor role: 'com.jcraft.jsch.UIKeyboardInteractive', implementation: 'org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.jsch.interactive.PrompterUIKeyboardInteractive', role hint: 'default' has a hint, but there are other implementations that don't"

Comment: So, I just ran mvn eclipse:clean -e from the command line as suggested by Matt. However, I see the same error, that the plugin requires maven 3.0 error. So, I am back to square one again.

Comment: What's the output of `mvn -v` on the command line?

Comment: It still shows maven 2.2.1 and java 1.7 for mvn -v. However, my M2_HOME is set to "C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0" and JAVA_HOME is set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0" and in the Path I have added "%M2_HOME%\bin" and similarly for JAVA_HOME

Comment: ok. One more additional information. From my eclipse -> right clicked on the project and select open command window here. In this cmd if I do mvn --v, it shows older versions of maven and java that were configured in my system. However, if I open cmd directly, navigate to the project path and then run mvn --v, it shows the currently configured versions. and the mvn eclipse:clean command is a success. Why there is a difference in the behavior?

Comment: It sounds like Eclipse is setting it's own values for M2_HOME and PATH. I don't use Eclipse or Windows so I can't say exactly where to check. In your screenshot, is there a place in the Maven settings where you can set the Java version that it uses? I think that will be the place to configure this.

Comment: I am not sure why Eclipse is behaving this way. However, I just ran mvn clean compile in the command prompt that was launched directly. Ran mvn clean compile, which ended up in failure saying that a rule for required maven version [3.1.1, 3.2] was not honored. So, I set the M2_HOME to 3.1.1 and ran again. It worked this time. I think better I should use cmd instead of eclipse commands. One more suggestion. Could you suggest any good link that talks about setting own maven repository, creating a basic maven project and all?

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html) is pretty clear, he's using Eclipse on Ubuntu but I think it will be similar on Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go through this tutorial